# How do I display multiple inline outputs from a series of radio buttons in one popup?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set up a part number configuration tool that outputs variables based on several sets of radio buttons. I've managed to make a single set display, but I can't figure out how to duplicate the outputs. Ideally, for the values that are checked by default, I'd like the alert to read "The part number is:  (ledcolor) (shellcolor)" Any help is much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="An Interesting Title Goes Here" name="title">
<title>An Interesting Title Goes Here</title>
 <style>
 </style>
</head>
 <body>
 <DL id="led">
 <DT>LED Light Color:
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor1" VALUE="R" checked>
   Red
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor2" VALUE="A">
   Amber
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor3" VALUE="RA">
   Red/Amber Combination
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor4" VALUE="B">
   Blue
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor5" VALUE="RB">
   Red/Blue Combination
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor6" VALUE="G">
   Green
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor7" VALUE="W">
   White
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ledcolor" id="ledcolor8" VALUE="I">
   Infrared
</DL> 
<DL>
 <DT>Shell Color:
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="shellcolor" id="shellcolor1" VALUE="Y" checked>
   Yellow
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="shellcolor" id="shellcolor2" VALUE="O">
   Orange
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="shellcolor" id="shellcolor3" VALUE="BL">
   Blue
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="shellcolor" id="shellcolor4" VALUE="BK">
   Black
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="shellcolor" id="shellcolor5" VALUE="OD">
   Olive Drab Green
 <DD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="shellcolor" id="shellcolor6" VALUE="T">
   Tan
</DL>
<button onclick=display()>Show Part Number</button>

<script>
function display() {
    var m = getRadioValue("ledcolor").value;
    var s = getRadioValue("shellcolor").value;
    alert("The part number is: " +m +"-"+ s);}
function getRadioValue(theRadioGroup)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup);
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i].checked)
        {
            alert("The part number is: " +elements[i].value);
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want one function to run for multiple groups of `radio` buttons? If so then why not assign a `class` to them? Or you could just use a `queryselector` targeting the class and selected items which will then only return 2 items since you have two groups?

Comment: I'd like one function to display the VALUE field of multiple selected radio button groups.

Comment: You can do this by assigning a `class` name to all those elements but where have you tried to run one function for both groups? I see no attempt(s) of your own. If you have any please include them in your question and I will see if I can explain why your attempt(s) didn't function as intended and then maybe offer a solution or alternate method.

Comment: Sorry--I removed that part because it didn't work. This is what I had:

`<button onclick=display()>Show Part Number</button>

<script>
function display() {
    var m = getRadioValue("ledcolor").value;
    var s = getRadioValue("shellcolor").value;
    alert("The part number is: " +m +"-"+ s);}`

Comment: Please update your question rather than posting the source code into the comments. Here is a very simple example of my suggestion but without trying your attempt(s) and explaining why it didn't function as intended I don't want to post a answer so if you could add that into your question it would be appreciated and I will give a detailed explanation of my example. https://jsfiddle.net/7osjdoqL/

Comment: I see you have updated your question, thank you for that. Take a look at my example, let me know if that is what you are expecting and let me know of anything withing the source code you do not understand so I can give more details within my answer. Obviously I don't want to be explaining line for line as that would become a tutorial so if I know what you don't understand I will be more than happy to explain the best I can for you. **Edit:** if you want multiple actions to the values this can be done too with very minor changes to my suggestion. **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/7osjdoqL/1/

Comment: Question updated--this is my first question so I'm still getting the hang of it :)

I need to be able to address the output values separately (to include the hyphen shown in the updated display()function

Comment: That for loop can be used to do what you want `display()` to do as the values are handled one by one (on their own)

Comment: I know this is likely painfully simple, but I just can't wrap my brain around it--how would the for loop integrate to get the values separately but still output in one alert box?

Comment: Well if you want to output within one alert you want to see my first example as that outputs one alert with both values. Are you wanting to preform single actions for the values but then alert the values of both because if so then that can also be done.... But I'd like to also know what you don't understand withing the example I have provided and understand exactly what you want to do with the values so I can provide you with a answer...

Comment: This is going to function as a part-number selection tool. Users will choose the options (here, ledcolor and shellcolor) then I need to format those into the form that is used for the part numbering system, in this case, with the first radio button of each set selected, it would display "The part number is:  R-Y."  I need to address the values separately so that I can insert the hyphen between the "R" and the "Y"

Comment: So for the `display()` function would it help for you to pass the `name` and selected `value` if so I can amend it to do exactly that but I'm curious to where (which function/at what point) you want the alert to display both values? I can understand the values of this will function with something else you have but I'm wondering if part of what I have provided within my examples could also be used to simply the other source you wish to run....

Comment: **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/7osjdoqL/2/ of passing the name and value into `display()` but will output separate alerts as the function will be called at different times but you can still put it into one alert by doing this after the for loop  **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/7osjdoqL/3/ But I'm not 100% on your expectations or your intent of the `name` / `value` so without knowing I cannot help....

Comment: I think I'm understanding you clearly--This function is a standalone--it's not a part of anything bigger. The idea is that a user would get to the page, enter the radio values, click the button, and then write down the part number from the alert. So the alert should be displayed last, after all radio buttons are selected.

Comment: Looking at your example, No I don't need to pass the NAME through, just the value

Comment: Well if you explain the expectations of `display()` and how/when/order you want things to function I will see if I can amend my example for you and as explained before with a detailed explanation of anything you don't understand.